# Bar graphs in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wrote the following in matlab to plot the bars. However I want to change the x label that is 1 to 'Batch One' and 2 to 'Batch Two'. How do I do that? Thank you.

```
figure
y=[6,5; 3 2]
hb=bar(y)
hb(1).FaceColor='r';
hb(2).FaceColor='b';
legend('Apples','Bananas')

plot_easy_bar('Anything')
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Use the 'XTickLabel' setting for the axes.

```
set(gca, 'XTick', [1, 2], 'XTickLabel', {'Batch one', 'Batch two'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Draw the bar graph by specifying `x` in the proper format. The [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#mw_f8592ec5-92b3-4f0f-acb0-128a337a575a) states the valid datatypes as the following:

> **Data Types:** single | double | int8 | int16 | int32 | int64 | uint8 | uint16 | uint32 | uint64 | categorical | datetime | duration

In your case, `categorical` is the datatype to use for `x`. So, it will be:

```
hb = bar(categorical({'Batch One','Batch Two'}), y);
```